# Proving Topology Induced by $b_s$-Pseudo Metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have asked a question about  [Topology Induced by $b_s$-pseudo metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3951188/topology-induced-by-b-s-pseudo-metric) before. The following paragraph is a part of the answer:

The topology induced by $B(F)$ is formed in the standard way. First let
$$\mathscr{B}=\left\{\bigcap\mathcal{C}:\mathcal{C}\subseteq B(F)\text{ is finite}\right\}\,,$$
the set of all intersections of finitely many of the open balls in $B(F)$; then $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for $\tau$, i.e., $\tau$ is the set of all unions of members of $\mathscr{B}$.

By the definiton given above, I tried to prove that the topology induced by $B(F)$ **is indeed** a topology. But I got stuck on proving that any finite intersection of elements of $\tau$ is also in $\tau$.

Given any $A, A^* \in \tau$, then there exist $\mathcal{D}, \mathcal{D}^* \subset \mathscr{B}$ where $A = \bigcup \mathcal{D}$ dan $A^* = \bigcup \mathcal{D}^*$. Because $\mathcal{D}, \mathcal{D} \subset \mathscr{B}$, then $$\mathcal{D}=\{\cap \mathcal{C}_1, \cap \mathcal{C}_2, \cdots, \cap \mathcal{C}_i, \cdots | \mathcal{C}_i=\{B_{i1},B_{i2},\cdots, B_{in_i}\}, i=1,2,\cdots\}$$
where $B_{in_i}\in B(F)$ for all $i=1,2,\cdots$ and $$\mathcal{D}^*=\{\cap \mathcal{C}_1^*, \cap \mathcal{C}_2^*, \cdots, \cap \mathcal{C}_j^*, \cdots | \mathcal{C}_j^*=\{B_{j1}^*,B_{j2}^*,\cdots, B_{jn_j}^*\}, j=1,2,\cdots\}$$
where $B^*_{jn_j}\in B(F)$ for all $j=1,2,\cdots$ and $n_i,n_j\in\mathbb{N}$ for all $i$ and $j$. Therefore we can write $A$ and $A^*$ as
\begin{align*}
   A = (B_{11}\cap B_{12}\cap\cdots B_{1n_1}) \cup (B_{21}\cap B_{22}\cap\cdots B_{1n_2}) \cup \cdots\\
   A^* = (B_{11}^*\cap B_{12}^*\cap\cdots B_{1n_1}^*) \cup (B_{21}^*\cap B_{22}^*\cap\cdots B_{1n_2}^*) \cup \cdots
  \end{align*}
By taking $\cap \mathcal{C}_i = X_i$ dan $\cap \mathcal{C}_j^* = Y_j$, we have
\begin{align*}
   A = X_1 \cup X_2 \cup \cdots\\
   A^* = Y_1 \cup Y_2 \cup \cdots
  \end{align*}
Furthermore, we have
\begin{align*}
   A\cap A^* = & (X_1 \cup X_2 \cup \cdots) \cap (Y_1 \cup Y_2 \cup \cdots)\\
   = & (X_1 \cap (Y_1 \cup Y_2 \cup \cdots)) \cup (X_2 \cap (Y_1 \cup Y_2 \cup \cdots)) \cup \cdots\\
   = & [(X_1\cap Y_1)\cup(X_1\cap Y_2)\cup(X_1\cap\cdots)] \cup\\ & [(X_2\cap Y_1)\cup(X_2\cap Y_2)\cup(X_2\cap\cdots)] \cup \cdots
  \end{align*}

We know that $X_i, Y_j \in \mathscr{B}$, then $X_i\cap Y_j \in \mathscr{B}$. Thus, $A\cap A^* \in  \tau$.

I realized later that $\mathcal{D}$ can also be uncountable, but I don't have any clue on how to prove $A\cap A^* \in  \tau$ if $\mathcal{D}$ is uncountable.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\mathcal{B}$ is closed under finite intersections, basically by definition (as is any base defined from a subbase).

Then apply

$$\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i \cap \bigcup_{j \in J} B_j = \bigcup_{(i,j) \in I \times J} (B_i \cap B_j) $$

so that a union of base elements intersected with another has the same form again. This fact holds for all index sets and is just basic set theory (easily proved by a double inclusion).